# Get Average and upload into new db table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to get the average of the columns in my table and then insert the averages into a second table, I have over 30 columns so I would rather not have to do them all individually if possible

```
 command.CommandText = " INSERT INTO  FaceAverages(`rightEyeRightUpper`),(`rightEyeLeftUpper`),(`rightEyeRightLower`),(`rightEyeLeftLower`),(`leftEyeRightUpper`)... FROM(SELECT AVG (rightEyeRightUpper),(rightEyeLeftUpper),(rightEyeRightLower),(`rightEyeLeftLower`)... FROM 'FaceDistancesHappy')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you table FaceAverages  contains the coulmns

```
 `rightEyeRightUpper`,`rightEyeLeftUpper`,`rightEyeRightLower`,
      `rightEyeLeftLower`,`leftEyeRightUpper`...
```

then you could use an insert select as

```
command.CommandText = " INSERT INTO  FaceAverages(`rightEyeRightUpper`,`rightEyeLeftUpper`,
    `rightEyeRightLower`,  `rightEyeLeftLower`,`leftEyeRightUpper`... )
  SELECT AVG(rightEyeRightUpper), AVG(rightEyeLeftUpper), 
       AVG(rightEyeRightLower), AVG(`rightEyeLeftLower`), ... 
  FROM 'FaceDistancesHappy'";
```

declaring all the column you want insert crresponding to all the column you want select .  and using the AVG() function for each column in select